# multiple values suggestion in textbox with jquery autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

Could someone kindly help me adding some modifications to my php code so that it allows users to get more than one auto-suggestion? (Now it works fine for one value, but I would like that he/she receives auto suggest for more values, (for example after inserting a comma, again auto-complete suggestions will be shown ).

This is the HTML code:

```
  <p><label>Actor/actress:</label><input type='text' name='name' value=''  class='auto'></p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

     //autocomplete
       $(".auto").autocomplete({
          source: "actorsauto.php",
           minLength: 2
       });                             
    });
  </script>
```

and this is php code:

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxxx');
define('DB_NAME', 'imdb');


if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();

    try {

        $conn=new PDO('mysql:dbname=imdb;host=localhost', 'root', 'xxxxx');
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT name FROM name WHERE name LIKE :term');
        $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $return_arr[] =  $row['name'];
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }


    /* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}


?>
```

I am newbie in jquery and php and appreciate all your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can put together a where statement by spliting the search term, for example at every space the user typed. Let's say he searched for `music cd`. The following code would get everything that has the string `cd` or `music` in it.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT name FROM name WHERE :where');
if($_GET['term']){
  $termParts = explode(' ', $_GET['term']);
  $whereParts = array()
  foreach($termParts as $term){
    $whereParts[] "name LIKE '%".$term."%'";
  }
  $where = implode(' OR ', $whereParts);
} else {
  $where = 1;
}
$stmt->execute(array('where' => $where));
```

Comment: sorry, but it didnt change ... I mean I insert Leonardo dicaprio and then I want to insert another actor (let's say after a space or comma), but for the second actor that I write,  autocomplete doesnt suggest any name..